# What is the best way to work with xml configurations file to my application in java?

Tags: java, xml

Hi experts
What is the best way to work with xml configurations file to my application in java?
Any XML parser that i found in the internet is too complex.
thank you guys.
Regards.
elad.

Comment: Why XML if you do not need the complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What XML parsers have you tried?

What you could do is to have a class named AppSettings (for example) and then serialize it with [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). Once you start your application, this class is loaded and you make the appropriate changes. I doubt that you will find something simpler than XStream though. Also, telling us what you have done will only help us help you...

Comment: I've just think about serialize my configuration but I want to allow the user to change the xml configuration in editor and not in my program. I don't want to wast my time to write a GUI for configuration.

Comment: That a look at the XStream tutorial: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html    

As you can see, the XML stored in the file is pretty readable, provided you have property names that make sense. Thus, I think that XStream does what you need :)

Comment: JAXB is easier to use than XStream:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 1):

JAXB is the easiest way to interact with XML in Java.

Comment: JAXB is easier than XStream,check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for using the XML format as configuration file? For most applications a [property file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is sufficient and offers a much lower learning curve.